# HashTable With Double Hash - Standard Implementation for Contains method

Tags: c++, hash, hashtable, contains

I am creating a hash table with a double hash implementation in c++. I want to check if certain keywords are inside of the hashtable. I do this by first hashing the word and if the spot has been already taken, I continously rehash with a second function in a loop until it finds an open spot likeso:

```
int index = hash(word) % size;

if(arr[index] == "")
{
    arr[index] = word;
}
//index already contains something, rehash until find better spot
else
{
    int factor = 1;
    while(arr[index] != "")
    {
        index = (hash(word) + (factor*hash2(word))) % size;
        factor++;
    }
}
```

As of right now, there will be a loop that will continuously run until it finds the key inside the hashtable.

I am having difficulty in trying to understand how I would implement the contains method. My problem is that what if the word does NOT exist in the table?

Right now, the only implementation I can think of is to only double hash a certain amount of time before doing a linear probe. That way, I know the end case of the loop when searching for the key would be when I reach right back to the original hash. But I feel as if this is too inefficient. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing

Comment: Woops, wrong link: Quadratic probing is what I was going for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_probing

Comment: Hey, thank you for the reply. I also messed up - could you see the edited question?

Comment: If `hash2(word)` returns a multiple of `size` - then varying factor makes no difference to the bucket selection and your program loops ad infinitum.  What if `hash2(word)` returns `size / 2` - it'll only search 2 buckets.  Anyway, when using open addressing you normally need to mark the buckets as unused somehow - when you hit an unused bucket you know a key isn't in the table.  You can sometimes do that by reserving a value of the key type to use as a sentinel value (e.g. if valid keys are 1..N, you might use 0).  Other times, buckets need to store a bool and a key, or a separate `bitset<>`